# Change Price Based on Bundle Options

Tags: price, discount, bundle, rules

I have been playing around with bundled products and was wondering if you guys could help with something. In this situation the base product is a phone and the bundle options are different phone plans.

I would like to create a bundled product with these features:

1) Product with no bundle option selected displays one price (e.g. buying a phone without a plan will cost you full retail price)

2) Adding a bundle option will reduce the base price of the item, often for promotional purposes (E.g. the phone is $60 by itself, but if you buy it with a plan, the phone is free - or $1 if needed).

3) This is a nice-to-have, not essential. I would like to be able to specify precisely **which** bundle options (plans) will drop the price of the base product (phone). It would also be great if I could even specify **how much** ($ or %) each bundle option drops the price of the base product.

Please let me know if this is possible! If you guys have any extension suggestions that might be able to do this, that's great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want bundles here? Seems more natural to me to use configurable:

Option: phone, SIM-free
              phone, with plan

Choosing with plan opens up plan choices. For an client of ours we've built something similar, where based upon height attribute, choices for length and width were loaded. I think some default logic is available even, like can be seen with color and sizes in the sample data demo store.

Comment: Melvyn, thanks for your response! The problem is that I am using a PIN/Serial code system to issue pins for the plans, so they need to each have their own SKU.  I tried looking into catalog price rules but it seems these cant be applied to bundle items. Essentially I just want the base price to change depending on which bundle option is selected.

Comment: I don't understand. When you order ten serials from carrier Rural Coverage, you get an invoice with ten order lines not one line specifying ten serials?